# C Sudoku solver by backtracking getting stuck

Tags: c, backtracking

I'm trying to use backtracking to code a sudoku solver in C, but it is getting stuck at some point. All the other functions are working well, so I can't seem to find the problem. The function was supposed to call itself using the next number as a parameter. returning one of the value is valid and zero when it Isn't. This in turn was supposed to trigger the backtracking. It should work like this until there are no more lines left.

input:

5 3 X X 7 X X X X
6 X X 1 9 5 X X X
X 9 8 X X X X 6 X
8 X X X 6 X X X 3
4 X X 8 X 3 X X 1
7 X X X 2 X X X 6
X 6 X X X X 2 8 X
X X X 4 1 9 X X 5
X X X X 8 X X 7 9

expected output:

5 3 4 | 6 7 8 | 9 1 2
6 7 2 | 1 9 5 | 3 4 8
1 9 8 | 3 4 2 | 5 6 7
- - - - - - - - - - -
8 5 9 | 7 6 1 | 4 2 3
4 2 6 | 8 5 3 | 7 9 1
7 1 3 | 9 2 4 | 8 5 6
- - - - - - - - - - -
9 6 1 | 5 3 7 | 2 8 4
2 8 7 | 4 1 9 | 6 3 5
3 4 5 | 2 8 6 | 1 7 9

what I end up getting:

5 3 1 | 2 7 6 | 4 9 8 
6 2 4 | 1 9 5 | 7 3 0 
0 9 8 | 0 0 0 | 0 6 0 
- - - - - - - - - - -
8 0 0 | 0 6 0 | 0 0 3 
4 0 0 | 8 0 3 | 0 0 1 
7 0 0 | 0 2 0 | 0 0 6 
- - - - - - - - - - -
0 6 0 | 0 0 0 | 2 8 0 
0 0 0 | 4 1 9 | 0 0 5 
0 0 0 | 0 8 0 | 0 7 9

Here is the backtracking function:

```
int solve(slot sudoku[9][9],int line, int column){
    int num=1;  
    while(sudoku[line][column].fix==1){
        column++;
    }
    if(line==9){
        return 1;
    }
    for(num=1;num<10;num++){
        if(Valid(line,column,num)){
            sudoku[line][column].value=num;
            if(column<8){
                if(solve(sudoku,line,column+1)){
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            else if(column==8){
                if(solve(sudoku,line+1,0)){
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;


}
```

This is how I defined the "slot" struct. It's purpose was to "pin" the original values of the puzzle, so it wouldn't overwrite them. It worked by assigning "0" to the slots that could be altered by the function, and "1" to the slots that were to remain fixed.

```
typedef struct slot{
    int value;
    int fix;
}slot;
```

If someone could help me find the problem, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Can you explain in psuedocode how your code is supposed to work? I don't see anywhere where when your code backtracks it resets the positions it got wrong back to zero. From your output you can see how column 0 line 3 the logic couldn't figure out what to put there but instead of backtracking and removing zeros until it could make another guess it just gave up instead.

Comment: when I was thinking about it I figured It would work like this: dont know how to post readable code in the comments so i will just explain it istead

Comment: @Mordred you can edit your original post and provide more info. For example, it'd be nice to understand how your backtracking works and how your `slot` struct is defined.

Comment: New information added

Comment: post the `valid()` function.  Do you expect us to guess as to the contents of that function?

Comment: when asking a `runtime` question, you must post code that cleanly compiles, is short, and still exposes the problem.  One characteristic of such a post is a `main()` function.  Post the actual inputs, post the expected outputs, post the actual outputs.

Comment: in the `slot` struct, is the `fix` field what you are speaking of when you say: *It worked by assigning "0" to the slots that could be altered by the function, and "1" to the slots that were to remain fixed*

Comment: this code block: ` while(sudoku[line][column].fix==1)
    {
        column++;
    }` has no limit on the value of column.  Suggest: `for( ; column<9; column++ )
    {
        if( sudoku[line][column].fix==1)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }`

Comment: this code block: `if(line==9)
    {
        return 1;
    }` seems to always result in the last line+1 to be set to indicate a good number.

Comment: this code block: `else if(column==8){
                if(solve(sudoku,line+1,0)){
                    return 1;
                }
            }` would be better written as: `else if( line < 8 )
            {
                if( solve( sudoku, line+1, 0) )
                    return 1;
            }`

Comment: At the end of this code block: `while(sudoku[line][column].fix==1){
        column++;
    }` the variable `column` could be anything, including a value greater than 8.  so need to append this code block: `if( 8 < column ) { line++; if ( 8 < line ) { return 0; }`

Answer (score 1):

What do you do in or after this loop, when column overflows your array size?

```
  while(sudoku[line][column].fix==1)
  {
        column++;
  }
```

When column overflows, the rest of the function uses that value, it's passed as a parameter to `Valid()`, among other things.

If the number is fixed, shouldn't you just consider that as a valid solution and return 0 instead?

I don't see any code in your function that sets `sudoku`->value to zero.

[edit] But when column overflows, your function returns 0, without finding a solution.  The zeroes we see are uninitialized values.